# How do I call an API and print the value in a div when the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to call an API and then print the response inside a div tag. It might be easy doing this with jQuery, but I am trying to avoid that. Currently just a blank page is getting loaded.

```
<body>
    <div id="OnLoad"></div>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                document.getElementById('OnLoad').innerHTML = data;
            })
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
document.getElementById('OnLoad').addEventListener('load', myFunction)
```

```
<div id="OnLoad" onload="myFunction()"></div>
```

Basically, I can fix this by calling the function inside the script tag. But is there any way to call it from the div tag directly.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Div elements don't load external content. Since they don't load anything: they don't have a load event.

Just call `myFunction` straight after the end tag for the div… or don't use a function.

```
<div id="OnLoad"></div>
<script>
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            document.getElementById('OnLoad').innerHTML = data;
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>

    <div id="OnLoadBefore">
    <!-- This throws error as myFunction is not yet defined -->
      <script>myFunction('OnLoadBefore')</script>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        function myFunction(selector) {
            document.getElementById(selector).innerHTML = "Test Div Load";
        }
    </script>
    
    <div id="OnLoadAfter">
    <!-- This executes myFunction as myFunction is defined -->
      <script>myFunction('OnLoadAfter')</script>
    </div>
    
</body>
```

It is best practice to do such events with onload events when all page resources are available, `window.onload = function() { myFunction() }` will register the function to execute on load. body tag of html allows an onload event. See below snippet...

```js
function myFunction(selector) {
            document.getElementById(selector).innerHTML = "Test Div Load";
        }
function onLoad() {
  myFunction('OnLoadBefore');
  myFunction('OnLoadAfter');
}
```

```html
<body onload="onLoad()">

    <div id="OnLoadBefore"></div>
    
    <div id="OnLoadAfter"></div>
    
</body>
```